# How to make a div clickable but ignore the children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have something like a card which i want it to be clickable. The problem here is I have a data attribute that I need the value on the click event. Therefore when I click the image obviously it will get me undefined because the wrong element triggered the click event. So I added `pointer-events: none` to the image and it worked but even have to add it to the `figcaption` because this will also have the same behaviour.

```js
function App () {
  return (
    <figure
        onClick={(e)=>console.log(e.target.getAttribute("data-mode"))}
        data-mode="some-data-mode"
        className="game-mode-figure"
    >
      <img
          style={{pointerEvents: "none"}}
          className="img-fluid"
          src="https://via.placeholder.com/60x60"
          alt="English 4 Fun"
      />
      <figcaption>Sample Title</figcaption>
    </figure>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

So my question is basically, without having to set pointer-event none in everything, how can I make the Figure element be the only one to capture the click event ? As in, I click the image or where the figcaption is and it will behave like I clicked the figure element and I can access the data attribute.

Comment: or check like this ..`if(event.target.classList.contains('game-mode-figure')){...}`

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor I did this and still didn't work, I even tried `event.target != this`, but the problem with these checks is that i cann't make any of the area in the div unclickable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to your proposed requirement is to traverse to the closest element with the said data attribute - no need for `pointer-events: none` if you do this

```
onClick={(e) => {
  // of course you would only need to traverse if child is clicked
  // you can write additional logic for that checking
  let data_mode = e.target.closest("figure").getAttribute("data-mode");
}}
```

---

But to be answer complete, you can simplify your CSS like this:

```
figure * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: It seems your first approach is better in this situation since the only intention is to get that data attribute during the click event no matter which element was clicked